# When installing Fiona on Windows 8.1 it does not fetch correct GDAL version

Tags: python, gdal, installation, fiona, windows-8

When I try to install Fiona binary

```
C:\Python37\Scripts>pip install "D:/Fiona-1.8.13-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl"
```

using the `'Fiona-1.8.13-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl'` from the [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#fiona) I end up with the following error:

```
Processing d:\fiona-1.8.13-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: cligj>=0.5 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from
 Fiona==1.8.13) (0.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=4.0 in c:\users\taras dubrava\appdata\roam
ing\python\python37\site-packages (from Fiona==1.8.13) (7.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: click-plugins>=1.0 in c:\python37\lib\site-packag
es (from Fiona==1.8.13) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: munch in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from Fion
a==1.8.13) (2.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from
Fiona==1.8.13) (19.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.7 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from F
iona==1.8.13) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=4.0 in c:\users\taras dubrava\appdata\roam
ing\python\python37\site-packages (from Fiona==1.8.13) (7.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=4.0 in c:\users\taras dubrava\appdata\roam
ing\python\python37\site-packages (from Fiona==1.8.13) (7.1.2)
Collecting gdal~=3.0.2
  Using cached GDAL-3.0.4.tar.gz (577 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.7 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from F
iona==1.8.13) (1.12.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: gdal
  Building wheel for gdal (setup.py) ... -

code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code,
 __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Tem
p\pip-wheel-l3a00k58'
       cwd: C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-v9cce2x4\gdal_3c791
9e51a8f4da88c1e727a3eff659a\
  Complete output (28 lines):
  c:\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution optio
n: 'long_description_content_type'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  copying gdal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  copying ogr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  copying osr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  copying gdalconst.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  copying gdalnumeric.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo
  copying osgeo\gdal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo
  copying osgeo\gdalconst.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo
  copying osgeo\gdalnumeric.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo
  copying osgeo\gdal_array.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo
  copying osgeo\gnm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo
  copying osgeo\ogr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo
  copying osgeo\osr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo
  copying osgeo\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo
  Fixing build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\gdal.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\ogr.py build\li
b.win-amd64-3.7\osr.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\gdalconst.py build\lib.win-amd64-
3.7\gdalnumeric.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\gdal.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
\osgeo\gdalconst.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\gdalnumeric.py build\lib.win-a
md64-3.7\osgeo\gdal_array.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\gnm.py build\lib.win-
amd64-3.7\osgeo\ogr.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\osr.py build\lib.win-amd64-
3.7\osgeo\__init__.py
  Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
  Fixing build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\gdal.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\ogr.py build\li
b.win-amd64-3.7\osr.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\gdalconst.py build\lib.win-amd64-
3.7\gdalnumeric.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\gdal.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
\osgeo\gdalconst.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\gdalnumeric.py build\lib.win-a
md64-3.7\osgeo\gdal_array.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\gnm.py build\lib.win-
amd64-3.7\osgeo\ogr.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\osr.py build\lib.win-amd64-
3.7\osgeo\__init__.py
  Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
  running build_ext
  building 'osgeo._gdal' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C+
+ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for gdal
  Running setup.py clean for gdal
Failed to build gdal
Installing collected packages: gdal, Fiona
  Attempting uninstall: gdal
    Found existing installation: gdal 2.4.1
    Uninstalling gdal-2.4.1:
      Successfully uninstalled gdal-2.4.1
    Running setup.py install for gdal ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize;
sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\TARASD~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-v9cce2
x4\\gdal_3c7919e51a8f4da88c1e727a3eff659a\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\User
s\\TARASD~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-v9cce2x4\\gdal_3c7919e51a8f4da88c
1e727a3eff659a\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__
);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(cod
e, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local
\Temp\pip-record-7cb0xxo8\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-manage
d --compile --install-headers 'c:\python37\Include\gdal'
         cwd: C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-v9cce2x4\gdal_3c7
919e51a8f4da88c1e727a3eff659a\
    Complete output (28 lines):
    c:\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution opt
ion: 'long_description_content_type'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    copying gdal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    copying ogr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    copying osr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    copying gdalconst.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    copying gdalnumeric.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo
    copying osgeo\gdal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo
    copying osgeo\gdalconst.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo
    copying osgeo\gdalnumeric.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo
    copying osgeo\gdal_array.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo
    copying osgeo\gnm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo
    copying osgeo\ogr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo
    copying osgeo\osr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo
    copying osgeo\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo
    Fixing build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\gdal.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\ogr.py build\
lib.win-amd64-3.7\osr.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\gdalconst.py build\lib.win-amd6
4-3.7\gdalnumeric.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\gdal.py build\lib.win-amd64-3
.7\osgeo\gdalconst.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\gdalnumeric.py build\lib.win
-amd64-3.7\osgeo\gdal_array.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\gnm.py build\lib.wi
n-amd64-3.7\osgeo\ogr.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\osr.py build\lib.win-amd6
4-3.7\osgeo\__init__.py
    Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
    Fixing build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\gdal.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\ogr.py build\
lib.win-amd64-3.7\osr.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\gdalconst.py build\lib.win-amd6
4-3.7\gdalnumeric.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\gdal.py build\lib.win-amd64-3
.7\osgeo\gdalconst.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\gdalnumeric.py build\lib.win
-amd64-3.7\osgeo\gdal_array.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\gnm.py build\lib.wi
n-amd64-3.7\osgeo\ogr.py build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\osgeo\osr.py build\lib.win-amd6
4-3.7\osgeo\__init__.py
    Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
    running build_ext
    building 'osgeo._gdal' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual
C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
    ----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of gdal
  Moving to c:\python37\lib\site-packages\__pycache__\gdal.cpython-37.pyc
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-p97cc4m7\gdal.cpython
-37.pyc
  Moving to c:\python37\lib\site-packages\__pycache__\gdalconst.cpython-37.pyc
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-p97cc4m7\gdalconst.cp
ython-37.pyc
  Moving to c:\python37\lib\site-packages\__pycache__\gdalnumeric.cpython-37.pyc

   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-p97cc4m7\gdalnumeric.
cpython-37.pyc
  Moving to c:\python37\lib\site-packages\__pycache__\ogr.cpython-37.pyc
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-p97cc4m7\ogr.cpython-
37.pyc
  Moving to c:\python37\lib\site-packages\__pycache__\osr.cpython-37.pyc
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-p97cc4m7\osr.cpython-
37.pyc
  Moving to c:\python37\lib\site-packages\gdal-2.4.1.dist-info\
   from c:\python37\lib\site-packages\~dal-2.4.1.dist-info
  Moving to c:\python37\lib\site-packages\gdal.py
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-vaihk_24\gdal.py
  Moving to c:\python37\lib\site-packages\gdalconst.py
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-vaihk_24\gdalconst.py

  Moving to c:\python37\lib\site-packages\gdalnumeric.py
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-vaihk_24\gdalnumeric.
py
  Moving to c:\python37\lib\site-packages\ogr.py
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-vaihk_24\ogr.py
  Moving to c:\python37\lib\site-packages\osgeo\
   from c:\python37\lib\site-packages\~sgeo
  Moving to c:\python37\lib\site-packages\osr.py
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-vaihk_24\osr.py
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\__pycache__\epsg_tr.cpython-37.pyc
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-wyx71hec\epsg_tr.cpyt
hon-37.pyc
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\__pycache__\esri2wkt.cpython-37.pyc
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-wyx71hec\esri2wkt.cpy
thon-37.pyc
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\__pycache__\gcps2vec.cpython-37.pyc
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-wyx71hec\gcps2vec.cpy
thon-37.pyc
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\__pycache__\gcps2wld.cpython-37.pyc
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-wyx71hec\gcps2wld.cpy
thon-37.pyc
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\__pycache__\gdal2tiles.cpython-37.pyc
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-wyx71hec\gdal2tiles.c
python-37.pyc
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\__pycache__\gdal2xyz.cpython-37.pyc
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-wyx71hec\gdal2xyz.cpy
thon-37.pyc
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\__pycache__\gdal_auth.cpython-37.pyc
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-wyx71hec\gdal_auth.cp
ython-37.pyc
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\__pycache__\gdal_calc.cpython-37.pyc
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-wyx71hec\gdal_calc.cp
ython-37.pyc
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\__pycache__\gdal_edit.cpython-37.pyc
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-wyx71hec\gdal_edit.cp
ython-37.pyc
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\__pycache__\gdal_fillnodata.cpython-37.pyc
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-wyx71hec\gdal_fillnod
ata.cpython-37.pyc
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\__pycache__\gdal_merge.cpython-37.pyc
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-wyx71hec\gdal_merge.c
python-37.pyc
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\__pycache__\gdal_pansharpen.cpython-37.pyc
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-wyx71hec\gdal_panshar
pen.cpython-37.pyc
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\__pycache__\gdal_polygonize.cpython-37.pyc
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-wyx71hec\gdal_polygon
ize.cpython-37.pyc
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\__pycache__\gdal_proximity.cpython-37.pyc
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-wyx71hec\gdal_proximi
ty.cpython-37.pyc
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\__pycache__\gdal_retile.cpython-37.pyc
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-wyx71hec\gdal_retile.
cpython-37.pyc
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\__pycache__\gdal_sieve.cpython-37.pyc
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-wyx71hec\gdal_sieve.c
python-37.pyc
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\__pycache__\gdalchksum.cpython-37.pyc
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-wyx71hec\gdalchksum.c
python-37.pyc
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\__pycache__\gdalcompare.cpython-37.pyc
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-wyx71hec\gdalcompare.
cpython-37.pyc
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\__pycache__\gdalident.cpython-37.pyc
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-wyx71hec\gdalident.cp
ython-37.pyc
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\__pycache__\gdalimport.cpython-37.pyc
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-wyx71hec\gdalimport.c
python-37.pyc
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\__pycache__\gdalmove.cpython-37.pyc
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-wyx71hec\gdalmove.cpy
thon-37.pyc
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\__pycache__\mkgraticule.cpython-37.pyc
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-wyx71hec\mkgraticule.
cpython-37.pyc
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\__pycache__\ogrmerge.cpython-37.pyc
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-wyx71hec\ogrmerge.cpy
thon-37.pyc
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\__pycache__\pct2rgb.cpython-37.pyc
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-wyx71hec\pct2rgb.cpyt
hon-37.pyc
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\__pycache__\rgb2pct.cpython-37.pyc
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-wyx71hec\rgb2pct.cpyt
hon-37.pyc
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\epsg_tr.py
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-bz8c19yi\epsg_tr.py
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\esri2wkt.py
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-bz8c19yi\esri2wkt.py
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\gcps2vec.py
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-bz8c19yi\gcps2vec.py
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\gcps2wld.py
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-bz8c19yi\gcps2wld.py
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\gdal2tiles.py
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-bz8c19yi\gdal2tiles.p
y
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\gdal2xyz.py
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-bz8c19yi\gdal2xyz.py
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\gdal_auth.py
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-bz8c19yi\gdal_auth.py

  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\gdal_calc.py
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-bz8c19yi\gdal_calc.py

  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\gdal_edit.py
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-bz8c19yi\gdal_edit.py

  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\gdal_fillnodata.py
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-bz8c19yi\gdal_fillnod
ata.py
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\gdal_merge.py
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-bz8c19yi\gdal_merge.p
y
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\gdal_pansharpen.py
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-bz8c19yi\gdal_panshar
pen.py
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\gdal_polygonize.py
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-bz8c19yi\gdal_polygon
ize.py
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\gdal_proximity.py
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-bz8c19yi\gdal_proximi
ty.py
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\gdal_retile.py
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-bz8c19yi\gdal_retile.
py
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\gdal_sieve.py
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-bz8c19yi\gdal_sieve.p
y
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\gdalchksum.py
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-bz8c19yi\gdalchksum.p
y
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\gdalcompare.py
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-bz8c19yi\gdalcompare.
py
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\gdalident.py
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-bz8c19yi\gdalident.py

  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\gdalimport.py
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-bz8c19yi\gdalimport.p
y
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\gdalmove.py
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-bz8c19yi\gdalmove.py
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\mkgraticule.py
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-bz8c19yi\mkgraticule.
py
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\ogrmerge.py
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-bz8c19yi\ogrmerge.py
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\pct2rgb.py
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-bz8c19yi\pct2rgb.py
  Moving to c:\python37\scripts\rgb2pct.py
   from C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-bz8c19yi\rgb2pct.py
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'i
mport sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\TARASD~1\\AppData
\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-v9cce2x4\\gdal_3c7919e51a8f4da88c1e727a3eff659a\\setu
p.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\TARASD~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-
v9cce2x4\\gdal_3c7919e51a8f4da88c1e727a3eff659a\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokeniz
e, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n
'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record
 'C:\Users\TARASD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-7cb0xxo8\install-record.txt' -
-single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\python37\Incl
ude\gdal' Check the logs for full command output.
```

How can I resolve this problem?

I have Windows 8.1 Enterprise with Python 3.7.1.

Based on [this article](https://jingwen-z.github.io/how-to-install-python-module-fiona-on-windows-os/)

> GDAL version 3 is not yet supported.

When I run `C:\Python37\Scripts>pip freeze` I can see that `gdal==2.4.1` is installed on my PC.

Moreover, I am not sure whether I have to install additionally GDAL from GISInternals, i.e. [release-1911-x64-gdal-2-4-1-mapserver-7-2-2](http://www.gisinternals.com/query.html?content=filelist&file=release-1911-x64-gdal-2-4-1-mapserver-7-2-2.zip)?

Comment: you need to install them through https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: I did it already ... Or do you mean to reinstall all of them?

Comment: You need to install   the [GDAL](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal) version of Christoph Gohlke

Comment: Have you considered installing Fiona/GDAL with Conda? I would be happy to write up an answer based on Conda if it would help you.

Comment: @Aaron, thank you for your offer. I would firstly like to install Fiona/GDAL without Conda

Comment: @Aaron, can you be so kind and post your you solution as well, please. Thank you

Comment: @Taras Will do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was easier than I expected. I found it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60767145/5791355) on the Stack Overflow, despite a recommendation mentioned in [this article](https://jingwen-z.github.io/how-to-install-python-module-fiona-on-windows-os/), where installing the GDAL 3 was not suggested. Also, pay attention to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13144158/python-geos-and-shapely-on-windows-64#comment28020766_17849389), where it states to *"install the version that matches your Python installation"*.

So, there are two points that I comprehended when installing wheels. They shall match:

1. the version of your Python, e.g. Python 3.7
2. the bit version of your Python, e.g. 64

So, I have firstly installed ["GDAL-3.1.4-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl"](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal) with uninstalling the current version of GDAL, i.e. `gdal 2.4.1`.

```
C:\Python37\Scripts>pip install "D:/GDAL-3.1.4-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl"
Processing d:\gdal-3.1.4-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: GDAL
  Attempting uninstall: GDAL
    Found existing installation: gdal 2.4.1
    Uninstalling gdal-2.4.1:
      Successfully uninstalled gdal-2.4.1
Successfully installed GDAL-3.1.4
```

Secondly, I installed ["D:/Fiona-1.8.18-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl"](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#fiona).

```
C:\Python37\Scripts>pip install "D:/Fiona-1.8.18-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl"
Processing d:\fiona-1.8.18-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in c:\users\taras dubrava\appdata\roaming
\python\python37\site-packages (from Fiona==1.8.18) (2019.11.28)
Requirement already satisfied: click<8,>=4.0 in c:\users\taras dubrava\appdata\r
oaming\python\python37\site-packages (from Fiona==1.8.18) (7.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: click-plugins>=1.0 in c:\python37\lib\site-packag
es (from Fiona==1.8.18) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.7 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from F
iona==1.8.18) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from
Fiona==1.8.18) (19.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: munch in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from Fion
a==1.8.18) (2.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cligj>=0.5 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from
 Fiona==1.8.18) (0.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: gdal~=3.1.2 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (fro
m Fiona==1.8.18) (3.1.4)
Requirement already satisfied: click<8,>=4.0 in c:\users\taras dubrava\appdata\r
oaming\python\python37\site-packages (from Fiona==1.8.18) (7.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: click<8,>=4.0 in c:\users\taras dubrava\appdata\r
oaming\python\python37\site-packages (from Fiona==1.8.18) (7.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.7 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from F
iona==1.8.18) (1.12.0)
Installing collected packages: Fiona
Successfully installed Fiona-1.8.18

C:\Python37\Scripts>python
Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:57:15) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD6
4)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import fiona
>>>
```

And finally, I was able to install [geopandas](https://geopandas.org/)

```
C:\Python37\Scripts>pip install geopandas
Collecting geopandas
  Downloading geopandas-0.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (962 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 962 kB 3.3 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.23.0 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (
from geopandas) (0.25.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyproj>=2.2.0 in c:\users\taras dubrava\appdata\r
oaming\python\python37\site-packages (from geopandas) (2.6.1.post1)
Requirement already satisfied: shapely in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from ge
opandas) (1.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: fiona in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from geop
andas) (1.8.18)
Requirement already satisfied: gdal~=3.1.2 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (fro
m fiona->geopandas) (3.1.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in c:\users\taras dubrava\appdata\roaming
\python\python37\site-packages (from fiona->geopandas) (2019.11.28)
Requirement already satisfied: click-plugins>=1.0 in c:\python37\lib\site-packag
es (from fiona->geopandas) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.7 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from f
iona->geopandas) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from
fiona->geopandas) (19.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: click<8,>=4.0 in c:\users\taras dubrava\appdata\r
oaming\python\python37\site-packages (from fiona->geopandas) (7.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: munch in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from fion
a->geopandas) (2.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cligj>=0.5 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from
 fiona->geopandas) (0.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: click<8,>=4.0 in c:\users\taras dubrava\appdata\r
oaming\python\python37\site-packages (from fiona->geopandas) (7.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: click<8,>=4.0 in c:\users\taras dubrava\appdata\r
oaming\python\python37\site-packages (from fiona->geopandas) (7.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.7 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from f
iona->geopandas) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (fr
om pandas>=0.23.0->geopandas) (2019.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (f
rom pandas>=0.23.0->geopandas) (1.17.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.6.1 in c:\python37\lib\site-pa
ckages (from pandas>=0.23.0->geopandas) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.7 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from f
iona->geopandas) (1.12.0)
Installing collected packages: geopandas
Successfully installed geopandas-0.8.1

C:\Python37\Scripts>python
Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:57:15) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD6
4)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import geopandas
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've installed fiona & gdal on a few machines running windows using pipwin (If I remember correctly, all of them were windows 10 pro).

Please follow the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54734667/error-installing-geopandas-a-gdal-api-version-must-be-specified-in-anaconda).

```
pip install wheel    
pip install pipwin
```

Thereafter, try pipwin for every package that fails to install with pip install

```
pipwin install numpy
pipwin install pandas
pipwin install shapely
pipwin install gdal
pipwin install fiona
pipwin install pyproj
pipwin install six
pipwin install rtree
pipwin install geopandas
```

This solution ought to work with your version of windows as well.